# "too many arguments in [ (test) statement"

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, test, arithmetic

this is my first "if-else" script on linux.
It gives the error
**[: too many arguments**

Code:

```
n=0
if [ $n % 2 -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "even number"
fi
```

How to correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math in `bash` must be performed in `arithmetic context`. In your current implementation, you are supplying "$n", "%", and "2" as args to `[`, which does not perform math. Here is an example which performs that math n arithmetic context:

```
if [ "$((n % 2))" -eq 0 ]
```

In the above example, the results of the `$(())` are expanded by the shell before it is seen by the `[` command. You can simplify this by removing the call to `[`:

```
if (( (n % 2) == 0 ))
```

Comment: Thank You.The first method worked.
But i just used the following line which also worked.
_if [ `expr $n % 2` -eq 0 ]_
this is causing some confusion.

Comment: @Pradeep in [ expr $n % 2 -eq 0 ] you are calling test using six arguments. Hence the rule covering five or more arguments applies: "The expression is parsed and evaluated according to precedence using the rules listed above." (Bash Reference) Evaluating 'expr $n % 2' brings that down to three parameters and then the rule for 3 arguments applies.